# How can I build object files with Cargo?

Tags: linux, rust, rust-cargo, uefi

To build an UEFI executable, I need to build an object file from my library. I can then link it to the right PE format with `pei-x86-64 subsystem 10`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier to just configure Cargo to use the linker you need. Create a *target* file, which is a blob of JSON describing the target architecture. Something like this may work, but I cannot test it:

```
{
  "linker": "pei-x86-64",
  "pre-link-args": [
    "subsystem",
    "10"
  ]
}
```

Then, execute Cargo with `cargo --target=my-target.json build`.